# Trying to append HTML elements.

Tags: jquery, html

```
1. var checkbox_html = $("<input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='attach'/>");
3. var span_html = $("<span class='style'>" + $(item).attr('value') + "</span>");
3. $("#disallowed_list").append('<li><label>' + checkbox_html + span_html + '</label></li>');
```

This results in

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

Why am I not getting the html elements here?

UPDATE:

I need to change the attribute of the name and value in the input checkbox too. So I have kept the $ in front of the checkbox_html value.

Like this,

```
$(checkbox_html).attr("name", $(item).attr('name'));
$(checkbox_html).attr("value", $(item).attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `checkbox_html` and `span_html` are jQuery objects. You can't just put them in the middle of a string and expect them to spit out HTML. In order to get the HTML, you can use the native `outerHTML`.

```
$("#disallowed_list").append('<li><label>' + checkbox_html.get(0).outerHTML + span_html.get(0).outerHTML + '</label></li>');
```

Also, in your second example, I see you're using `$(checkbox_html)`. You don't need to do this, because `checkbox_html` is already a jQuery object. You can just do this:

```
checkbox_html.attr("name", $(item).attr('name'));
checkbox_html.attr("value", $(item).attr('value'));
```

This is why it's best practice to prefix jQuery objects with $, so you won't accidentally double-wrap the object (not that it will break anything, but it's just poor practice). For example:

```
var $checkbox_html = $("<input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='attach'/>");
var $span_html = $("<span class='style'>" + $(item).attr('value') + "</span>");
```

Then use code like this to access those variables:

```
$checkbox_html.attr("name", $(item).attr('name'));
$checkbox_html.attr("value", $(item).attr('value'));
```

In this case, it's easy to see that `$($checkbox_html)` would be incorrect without having to go and check the variable type.

Comment: does checkbox_html.html() work ? It still shows empty . However for span_html.html () is giving the Html there.

Comment: this is because, in the checkbox you haven't mentioned the name & value...(they are just empty)...on the other side for the span..you have put the proper html as span value.

Comment: @tilaprimera Yeah I see what you mean, check my edit.

Comment: @tilaprimera Are you sure you implemented it correctly as per my post? It works for me, both my previous answer and updated answer can be seen working here: http://jsfiddle.net/m375L1jd/

Comment: Now it works, the previous one with the wrap was not working.

Comment: @tilaprimera I've included the `.wrap()` example in the jsFiddle in my previous comment, you can see it working there (if you need to support older browsers, it might be better than `.outerHTML`). http://jsfiddle.net/m375L1jd/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var checkbox_html = "<input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='attach'/>";
var span_html = "<span class='style'>" + $(item).attr('value') + "</span>";
$("#disallowed_list").append('<li><label>' + checkbox_html + span_html + '</label></li>');
```

You are getting `[object Object][object Object]` because of you are using `$` which is creating object of HTML

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfu707wh/)

If you want to set value also, you can do this:

```
var checkbox_html = "<input type='checkbox' name='"+$(item).attr('name')+"' value='"+$(item).val()+"' class='attach'/>";
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfu707wh/1/)

### Updates:

The way @tilaprimera wanted

```
var checkbox_html = $("<input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='attach'/>");
var span_html = $("<span class='style'>" + $(item).attr('value') + "</span>");
var li = $('<li></li>');
var label = $('<label></label>');

li.append(label);
label.append(checkbox_html);
label.append(span_html);
$("#disallowed_list").append(li);

$(checkbox_html).attr("name", $(item).attr('name'));
$(checkbox_html).attr("value", $(item).attr('value'));
```

[**Latest DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfu707wh/3/)

Comment: I wanted to do it that way but if the value has a space in it, the value was distorted as in value = "Year" book .... and to resolve that, I have been doing it the other way.

Comment: you can use `.trim()` method to avoid unnecessary spaces.

Comment: I have added code as OP wanted. See updated answer @tilaprimera